# How to change the value of matching property using json-query?

Tags: javascript

I using [json-query](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-query) because it lets me find by path inside the JSON object.

After I find it I want to replace the value with a new value and I expected it to affect the string, but it doesn't.

Is there a way to do it using with json-query? or rebuild this JSON again from the object but I can't find a way in the docs.

```
const jsonQuery = require("json-query");

var data = {
  people: [
    { name: "Matt", country: "NZ" },
    { name: "Pete", country: "AU" },
    { name: "Mikey", country: "NZ" }
  ]
};

const b = jsonQuery("people[country=NZ].name", {
  data: data
});

console.log({ b });

b.value = "bla";

console.log({ b }); // value === 'bla'

console.log({ data }); // value === 'Matt'
```

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-engelbart-4epxk?file=/src/index.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the entry in the `reference` subproperty returned by the query:

```
const b = jsonQuery("people[country=NZ].name", {
  data: data
});

b.references[0].name = 'bla';
```

See proof-of-concept example: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-kirch-g7zy2